# Is there anyway possible to have multi writer instance and load balance between them?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

Hey I am a fresher devOps Engineer. These days I am working on database's connectivity issues and scaling problems. One month before I migrated my RDS database to aurora cluster for scaling and high availability but unfortunately I found it with no benefits cuz I am not sure where in my application writer endpoint will be used and where reader. Nobody is sure about, the database should forward the traffic accordingly but I am unable to find the way. I found that on aurora only reader replicas can be used for load balancing, which is just waste of resources in my case. Even I used custom endpoint but it didnt worked, it says read access only in logs.
Now I want to know if the problem I am facing can be solved on existing aurora or I should migrate back to RDS and use 3 instances or clone of it. If so then how will I balance load between these 3 RDS instances. Don't suggest to not to use multi writers because My application has 99% writer work.